# Sending E-Mail Attachment via R with Dynamic File Path

Tags: r, email, dynamic, outlook, attachment

I need to send a file via R but the filename is dynamic and a variable is used to access the specific file I wanted.

I have run the below code.

```
checkID = 2271
file <- paste0("N:\\QC\\AUS\\IAMWkly_Retail_Check Working File_", checkID, ".xlsm")
Email[["attachments"]]$Add(file`)
```

But run on the error below:

```
<checkErrorInfo> 80020009 
No support for InterfaceSupportsErrorInfo
checkErrorInfo -2147352567
Error: Exception occurred.
```